# How to select a better GARCH model

Tags: r

I am using R to train GARCH model, `ugarchfit()`, to do forecasting. With different data, parameters, I get different model.

For example: Model 1, I have a longer time series input to the training process

```
*---------------------------------*
*          GARCH Model Fit        *
*---------------------------------*

Conditional Variance Dynamics   
-----------------------------------
GARCH Model : sGARCH(1,1)
Mean Model  : ARFIMA(2,0,4)
Distribution    : sged 

....

LogLikelihood : 1591.974
```

Model 2, I have a subset time series shared from Model 1 data set and input to the training process

```
*---------------------------------*
*          GARCH Model Fit        *
*---------------------------------*

Conditional Variance Dynamics   
-----------------------------------
GARCH Model : sGARCH(1,1)
Mean Model  : ARFIMA(1,0,0)
Distribution    : sged 
....

LogLikelihood : 942.8283
```

I skip many information of the models. I want to ask is there a way to compare these 2 models? So that I can select the best one?

Thank you very much

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for statistical advice rather than asking a specific programming question. If that's the case, you should ask your question at [stats.se] instead. Statistical questions are on topic there.

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should go to Cross Validated